# Fetch specific column value from result set in php

Tags: php, prepared-statement

MY code is:

```
try 
        {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("select userid,fname,type from native_users where email=:email and pass=:pass");
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $password);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                $_SESSION['uid']=$stmt->fetchColumn(0); //working

                $_SESSION['fname']=$stmt->fetchColumn(1); //not working
                $utype=$stmt->fetchColumn(3); // not working

                if($utype == "admin")
                {
                    // send to admin page 
                }
                else
                {
                    //send to user page
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo"Incorrect data.";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $conn = null;
```

I am new to PHP, I basically do Java.

I read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) that:

> There is no way to return another column from the same row if you use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.

In java, there is `ResultSet#getString()` funtion to do this.

What is the PHP equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$result = $sth->fetch();
$result[0] will give userid
$result[1] will give fname
$result[2] will give type
```

Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> fetchColumn(), Returns a single column from the next row of a result
>   set.

Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) for detail.

Comment: Please use the formatting features to improve readability. I did it for you this time. Also please explain why your solution works or helps. Please read the [answer] article in [help] for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PDO::fetchAll()` :

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();       
    foreach ($rows as $v) { 
      echo $v['userid'] . " " . $v['fname'] . " " . $v['type'] ;
    }        
  }
```

or just `print_r($rows)` you will notice that it's an associative array.